# Javascript: How to get the value from a checked radio button when more than one radio button is present

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value from a checked radio button and eventually pass that value into other functions. Currently I am only successful when I have one radio button in my html. As soon as I add another radio button with the same name my Javascript function does not work as I intended.

Here is my Javascript:

```
function RadioButtonValue (form) {
if (form.elements ["radio"].checked) {
return parseInt (form.elements["radio"].value)
}else{
return 0}
}

function totalRadio (form) {
var radio = RadioButtonValue (form)
form.elements ["total"].value =  radio
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" />1
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"/>2
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Radio Button Value" onclick="javascript:totalRadio(this.form)" />
            <br />
            <input type="number" name="total" />
    </form>
```

I am looking for the simplest Javascript solution, I think using a "for loop" is the solution I need but I am not sure.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a loop that will just iterate through the radio buttons in the form that's being processed so it doesn't add any other checked radio buttons.

```
function RadioButtonValue (form) {    
   var returnVal = 0;
   var radios = form.elements ["radio"];
   for(var r = 0; r < radios.length; r++) {
        if (radios[r].checked) { 
            returnVal = parseInt (radios[r].value);
        }
   }
  return returnVal;
}

function totalRadio (form) {
    var radio = RadioButtonValue (form)
    form.elements ["total"].value =  radio
}
```

Here it is in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PM8Jm/1/

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at using a loop! That is a huge help especially because I am looking at adding multiple radio buttons to my code in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `radio` attribute to select the element. Therefore your code faces the ambiguity when there are more than one radio button elements on the page. Instead use name or class attributes to select the radio button group. That will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will work for you.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="radio"]:checked').value;
```

HTML:

```
 <form>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" />1
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"/>2
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Radio Button Value" onclick="javascript:totalRadio(this.form)" />
            <br />
            <input type="number" name="total" />
    </form>
```

Comment: I've never seen document.querySelector, is there a benefit of using that over getElementById?

Comment: this one really cover your previous answer.
You should have edited the previous answer than giving this new answer

Comment: The **querySelector** solution will not work for IE8 and before. Use the **document.getElementsByName('radio')** and then loop through the result in those versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Sort and Simple Example using `JQuery`

**HTML**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<form>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" />1
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"/>2
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Radio Button Value">        
        <input type="number" id="total" name="total" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#btn').click(function () {
      $('#total').val($('input[name=radio]:radio:checked').val());    
  });
});
```

Here is JSFiddle : [Radio Button Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PM8Jm/1/)